# LDAP in Silverlight applications

Tags: c#, silverlight, ldap

We have an existing ASP.NET application in which we use LDAP to fetch the current logged in users' details to display on the web page and perform other actions.

We would like to use LDAP to authenticate and fetch users details in our new Silverlight application too(this application has both a Silverlight front end and a WCF service to feed data) . Is it possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly interact with LDAP in Silverlight.  For that, you must implement a WebService on your web server that will interact with Silverlight.  Then in your Silverlight application you will be able to use that Webservice.

Or, if your application is only gonna be used on Windows.  You can use WPF to create an XBAP application.  That will allow you to use the System.DirectoryServices directly since its using the full .NET framework.

Comment: you need to SSL you silverlight call to the webservice or else the user name password will be readable since its sent in clear text over basicHttpBinding, the only one that silverligt supports.